# How to use a value resolver when resolving a ctor parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, automapper

I have an entity which has no property setters but has a parameterized constructor:

```
public class Unit
{
    public int Id { get; }

    public Player Owner { get; }

    public Unit(int id, Player owner)
    {
        Id = id;
        Owner = owner;
    }
}
```

I also have a custom value resolver for AutoMapper which finds a player by its Id:

```
public class UnitOwnerResolver : IValueResolver<UnitDto, Unit, Player>
{
    private readonly IPlayerService m_playerService;

    public UnitOwnerResolver(IPlayerService playerService)
    {
        m_playerService = playerService;
    }

    public Player Resolve(UnitDto source, Unit destination, Player destinationMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return m_playerService.GetPlayer(source.OwnerId);
    }
}
```

Problem is, I can not create a proper mapping profile for this entity. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
CreateMap<UnitDto, Unit>()
    .ForCtorParam("id", options => options.MapFrom(unit => unit.Id))
    .ForCtorParam("owner", options => options.MapFrom<UnitOwnerResolver>();
```

The third line produces an error, as there is no overload for the `ICtorParamConfigurationExpression.MapFrom` method taking the value resolver:

> No overload for method 'MapFrom' takes 0 arguments

I'm expecting it to work like it does with the `ForMember` method where there IS such overload:

[image]

Can someone please suggest how I can create an instance of the entity using AutoMapper, ctor mapping and value resolvers? I can create a factory, of course, but if it is possible, I would like to stick to mapping to preserve a single approach throughout the application.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you want to implement that yourself, you cannot. You'll have to use one of the existing overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Solution working up to AutoMapper 11. Required `Options` property  has been made private in AutoMapper 12. [Migration guide.](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/12.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#resolutioncontext-options-was-removed)

---

You can do it with a little bit of hacking. You'll have to resolve to service yourself using `ServiceCtor` func that can be accessed via resolution context `Options`:

```
config.CreateMap<UnitDto, Unit>()
    .ForCtorParam("id", options => options.MapFrom(unit => unit.OwnerId))
    .ForCtorParam("owner", options => options.MapFrom((unitDto, context) =>
    {
        var playerService = context.Options.ServiceCtor(typeof(IPlayerService)) as IPlayerService;

        return playerService.GetPlayer(unitDto.OwnerId);
    }));
```

Comment: Unfortunately `context.Options` were removed in AutoMapper 12

Comment: Does not work anymore. Options is not present in newer versions of Automapper.

Comment: Sadly, this simply won't work anymore. You can resolve the needed dependencies on your own and carry them through `Items` dictionary, or hack your way around to options with reflection (the options are still there, but are a private field now). Both ways are unsatisfactory IMHO, so I won't include them in my answer.